# Cannot return a laravel download via ajax call

Tags: ajax, laravel, routes

I want the user to download a file and it doesn't really need to be via ajax, but it was the easiest way I found, but it's not working.

Here is my method from the Controller that I'm calling:

```
  public function download(Request $request) 
  {
      $dir = $request->get("directory");
      return response()->download($dir);
  }
```

Here is my ajax function:

```
function download(diretorio) {

    $.ajax({
      url: "/panel/download",
      data: {_token: jQuery(".token").val(), diretorio: diretorio},
      success: function(e) {

      }
    }).done(function(e) {  

    });
}
```

This function is being called inside this append:

```
$('#uploads tbody').append("<tr><td>" + fileName + "</td> <td><a class='btn btn-success' href='' onclick=\"download('" + item + "')\">Download</button></td></tr>");
    });
```

Here is my route, which is inside a group called panel:

```
Route::get('/download/', ['as' => 'files.download', 'uses' => 'Panel\ClientController@download']);
```

My first question is: Is it possible to make this call from ajax to a download response from laravel?

Second question: I cannot figure out how to replace the ajax call for a route to a laravel controller, is it possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. This is just with Laravel only though. Try this example:

HTML: (just call your GET route here)

```
<a href="/download/">download file(s)</a>
```

Download Function

```
public function download() 
{
      // $pathToFile : set to what you need
      return Response::download($pathToFile); 
}
```

Comment: Exactly, you don't need jQuery's ajax function.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to pass the directory as a parameter, this is why I used ajax.


So I`m trying to pass the url in a link like you said, like this: /download/public/painel/clients/4/filename.pdf

and in my route I have something like: Route::get('/download/{directory}', ['as' => 'files.download', 'uses' => 'Panel\ClientController@download']);

But I'm getting a page not found exception.

Comment: @GabrielAugusto Are you sure you're calling the right route? If so are you directing to an existing file?

Answer (score 0):

due to the fact that the directory path parameter has slashes, I think the route is expecting other parameters. So I decided not to pass the entire directory path, but only an ID and the name of the file. So my route became like this: Route::get('/download/{id}/{fileName}', ['as' => 'files.download', 'uses' => 'Painel\ClienteController@fazerDownload']);

And it worked. Thank you for the answers and efforts!